# Cordova 3.3 to 3.4, iOS Plugins don't load

Tags: ios, cordova

I recently updated from Cordova 3.3 to 3.4 and had no trouble with my Android build, but the ios version no longer loads any plugins. I then removed all the plugins and re-added them and rebuilt and they still don't load. This is what Xcode says:

```
CDVPlugin class CDVLocation (pluginName: Geolocation) does not exist.
ERROR: Plugin 'Geolocation' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
```

Any thoughts, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that deleting the `./plugins/ios.json` file allowed the plugins to be reinstalled. Now it is all running again.