# Apache Cordova (3.4) doesn't add plugin source to project compile list

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have written a simple Cordova plugin (for iOS) and every time I update the plugin (which is in a separate git repo), I remove the plugin and add it back to my Cordova project.

Recently, I discovered that my plugin source code files (.m files) do not get added to the list of Compile Sources (under build phase) and every time I do this, I have to open Xcode and add the files manually.

I didn't think that's the way it works. Is it? Or am I doing something wrong? Issue with *"cordova add plugin"*?

I don't pass the git repo URL to cordova, I just use ../plugin-dir. Like this:

```
$ cd myAppProject
$ cordova plugin remove com.example.myplugin
$ cordova plugin add ../MyPlugin
$ cordova plugin list
[ 'com.example.myplugin',
  'org.apache.cordova.camera',
  'org.apache.cordova.console',
  'org.apache.cordova.device',
  'org.apache.cordova.geolocation' ]
```

Your help is appreciated.

UPDATE: I created a fresh project and added and removed my plugin a few times and the Xcode project build settings file (project.pbxproj) is updated correctly. So there must be some issue with my other project.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22278241/1755718) answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277927/cordova-3-3-to-3-4-ios-plugins-dont-load may solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Any time you run `cordova plugin add XXXX` you have to run `cordova prepare` or `cordova build` for the files to placed in the platform projects.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem! And for the record, I always do prepare and compile after plugin reinstall. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry. It's good to add information like that in your question to avoid obvious answers.

Comment: I have the same problem. cordova prepare, or cordova build or the referenced question don't fix this. Any other ideas?

Comment: Same.  Doesn't fix for me :(